the Laplacian on a Riemannian manifold
I am reading a book "Geometric Analysis" by Ailana Fraser. And I am new with Laplacian. I know definition that it is a divergence of the gradient. How can I compute this equality?
$$\Delta_{\Sigma} x= \sum_{i=1}^k\nabla_{e_i}\nabla_{e_i}x-\nabla_{\nabla_{e_i}^{\Sigma}e_i}x$$
Where $e_i$ denotes orthonormal frame in a neighborhood of a point.
Also i would be glad if someone suggest a book where i can read some basics about it

The Laplacian is the divergence of the gradient. Equivalently it is the trace with respect to the Riemannian metric $g$ of the covariant Hessian, i.e.
$$\Delta x = tr_g(\nabla^2 x) = \sum_{i,j = 1}^{k} g^{ij}\nabla^2_{e_i,e_j} x,$$
where $g_{ij} = g(e_i,e_j) = \delta_{ij}$ since $e_i$ are orthonormal.
So $g^{ij} = \delta^{ij}$ and
$$\Delta x = \sum_{i,j = 1}^{k} \delta^{ij}\nabla^2_{e_i,e_j} x = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} \nabla^2_{e_i, e_i} x.$$
It is $\nabla^2_{X,Y} x = \nabla_X(\nabla_Y x) - \nabla_{\nabla_X Y} x$ and thus
$$\Delta x = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} \nabla^2_{e_i, e_i} x = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} \nabla_{e_i}(\nabla_{e_i} x) - \nabla_{\nabla_{e_i} e_i} x.$$
